# symplify boolean expression with comparison signs

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a library in python to simplify boolean expression with comparison expressions
e.g.

from:

```
(a < 10 & a <= 10) | b
```

to:

```
(a < 10) | b
```

Comment: That's not correct Python code (well, it _compiles_ but it doesn't do what you're assuming); in Python the boolean operators are `and`, `or`, `not`. And answering your question: no, that's not the job of a library, the compiler should take care of it.

Comment: I understand it's not python code, but I want something that will simplify a boolean expression such as the example I gave. Thank you.

Comment: @user2479104 what are `a` and  `b`?

Comment: assume they are integers for the sake of the example

Answer (score 2):

SymPy can do some simplification of this kind:

```
In [15]: from sympy import symbols

In [16]: a, b = symbols('a, b')

In [17]: condition = ((a < 10) & (a <= 10)) | b

In [18]: condition
Out[18]: b ∨ (a ≤ 10 ∧ a < 10)

In [19]: simplify(condition)
Out[19]: b ∨ a < 10
```

For more complicated problems you might need to tell SymPy how exactly to simplify the condition.

Comment: great example but it doesn't work when I ran the same code. I added `from sympy import simplify` but my condition shows the same output even after calling simplify. anything missing?

Comment: I ran that with current SymPy master branch so there may have been improvements since the last release